# Feedback on my Polynomial congruence solution

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I would like to check if my working is correct for this and if not where I’ve gone wrong.

$$5 x^{11} \equiv 7  \mod{17}$$

My steps are below:
Rearrange to find $x^{11} \equiv  5^{-1} \cdot 7 \mod{17}$. I find this to be $7 \cdot 7 = 49$ which is $15 \mod{17}$. Since $11$ and $\mod \phi(17)$ are coprime, there is one solution, I find the inverse of $11 \mod{16}$ which is $3$. Raise both sides to $3$ and get $15^3 \equiv 9 \mod{17}$. So my solution for $x$ is $9$.

Any feedback id much appreciated, excuse formatting as this was written on a phone.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $ 5x^{11}=7$ mod $17$ in your displayed equation? [To make a more than one character exponent put it between curly brackets.]

Comment: Yes, sorry someone else formatted it for me for which I am grateful

Comment: Fixed the formatting, thanks to whoever it was that did it initially.

Comment: $9$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @JohnLou

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but if you wanted to check manually, all you had to do was take $9^2 \mod 17$ and raise that to the fifth and multiply by nine and work all of that arithmetic out, and repeat the process a bunch of times.